# Macos/Linux ping command pinging incorrect IP address

Tags: bash, macos, url, terminal, ping

I would like to get the ip address of this `data.alpaca.markets` url. When I use the ping command on Macos, this is the ip address that it returns: `35.186.171.205`. I navigated to the IP address only to find that this isn't the website I wanted. How can I get the IP address of the URL above?

Comment: Stackoverflow is for questions about programming, not network troubleshooting; [superuser](https://superuser.com) would be a better place to ask about this. Also, that does appear to be the IP address that's being served for the data.alpaca.markets domain, although the server at that address does not appear to be set up to serve it. You should explain more about what's going on (is this your site?).

Comment: @GordonDavisson this is not my website, I am simply trying to make a HTTP request to it without a library (in C++)

Comment: Hmm, I take back what I said about the server not being set up for that domain. It looks like it is set up (and has an SSL certificate for data.alpaca.markets and everything), but I got an error for another reason (probably I didn't send a valid API query). So that's the right IP address, the problem is something else.

Comment: @GordonDavisson What do you think it is?

Comment: @GordonDavisson maybe its something to do with the domain having a prefix (data.alpaca.markets, not simply alpaca.markets). When I try pinging alpaca.markets (the main website), I get the correct IP address.

Comment: What makes you think it's the wrong address?

Comment: @GordonDavisson I went into data.alpaca.markets and the IP address and I got directed to different webpages

Comment: That's fairly normal. Web servers are often set up to serve different content depending on the name used to access them. It's called [name-based virtual hosting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting#Name-based). So if the server at 35.186.171.205 sees a request come in for `http://35.186.171.205/`, it's entirely normal for it to serve something different from what it serves for `http://data.alpaca.markets/`.

Comment: @GordonDavisson so how can I access data.alpaca.markets via an IP address?

Comment: You need to connect to 35.186.171.205, then send a HTTP/1.1 request that includes the header "`Host: data.alpaca.markets`".

Comment: @GordonDavisson when I do that, I get a status code of 301 (moved permanently) and an HTML page. I can post it if that'll help.What should I do?

Comment: I just tested it, and got a 301 response with a `Location: https://data.alpaca.markets/` header meaning it's redirecting you to the secure (https) version of the site. This is normal, it just means you need to access it over TLS (/SSL) on port 443 instead of plaintext on port 80.

Comment: @GordonDavisson it returns this: The HTTP request was sent to the HTTPS port.

Comment: That means you're using port 443, but not the TLS (/SSL) protocol. You *must* use TLS.